# why not to use passive voice in commit?

Tags: commit, git-commit, commit-message

I am not a native English speaker. I have a question about the commit message.
I would like to use passive voice in some situations.

I think it is reasonable enough to use passive voice in some commit. But I find some projects do not allow to commit messages with passive voice. Why is it?

I google it, and I only find the rules themselves. But no one explains the reason for the rule.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: You might prefer to ask this question on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com; it may be more on-topic there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. softwareengineering.stackexchange.com || english.stackexchange.com *may be* more relevant locations for question
2. **Any rules** are result of *accepted agreements* (or habits of rule-maker in case of dictatorship environment)

In common case active voice is preferred, because (*by agreement*) commit-message describe not "what was done" by committer, but "what must to do" changed code.

But, anyway, **you** can follow *any style*, as long as it does not interfere with the rest team